# How to create table view with progress bar?

Tags: views

I want to create a tabular view with progress bar. The drupal-6 view consists of goals of activities I need to do. I have created a content type called Goal that is composed of activities/task. I want to list the goals in a tabular view and show a progress bar in one of the column that indicates how many task/activities under the goals have been completed. How can I do it?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You either need

1. A custom views field
2. A themed/templated existing field.

A good option in D7 for progress bars is [jQuery UI progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/) ( API docs [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/) ), as it's shipped with core.

You can add the required JS with

```
drupal_add_library('system', 'ui.progressbar');
```